# Kafka Connect - how to get a failed task to restart with a new configuration

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Whenever we restart a failed task, it will ALWAYS pick up the config it had at the time of the failure, and run with that.. and THEN it picks up the new config.. and runs that as well.

We have connect jobs that we pause, update config, and then resume.  This works fine, unless the task has failed.

If we restart a failed task, even if the connector has an updated config, the task will launch with the old config.. run to completion/failure.. then a new task will be launched with the new config.

This can cause various data/etc issues.. if you really don't want that old task to run with that config.

Any ideas how to restart a connector with a failed task.. with a new config.. and NOT have the old config get invoked?

(running Kafka v2.5, btw)

Comment: have exactly the same issue

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it would make sense for the task to pick up the latest config.
For instance, let's assume that your connector fires up 10 distinct tasks and 1 of them fails. It won't make sense to have the remaining 9 tasks of the connector running with the older config while the failed task runs the newest config once it is restarted.

---

I would say that in cases you want to use a new/different configuration file when a task fails, it might make more sense to [restart the connector](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/references/restapi.html#post--connectors-(string-name)-restart) and not the individual task(s):

```
POST /connectors/connector-name/restart HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: Trying to find detailed information on what happened on a connector restart.  The issue we keep running into.. is that virtually no matter what we try, the task is first restarted with the old config, THEN it is updated with the new config... even if the connector has been updated.

Our current process is: pause connector, update config, resume the connector.  For source, this seems to be working.. for sink.. the connector is getting updated just fine.. but in the sink, the JDBC process has one sub-task per partition.. and some/most are getting updated.. but some run off the old config..

Comment: Per the documentation, restarting the connector will not restart the tasks... I would have to directly restart the task, which would result in the same issue.

Comment: @Brian Yeah that’s correct. Still makes no sense to me having tasks of the same connector running different config. If you want to use a newer config, stop the connector and strat another one with the new config

Comment: If you have a sink connector, pushing data to a particular table.. and the sink properties need to be adjusted... it makes total sense to adjust the config.. and resume it.  Most simple, direct path.  I should not be forced to create a new connector, simply to get the tasks to properly inherit the config changes.

if that was the case.. you should never update the config for a connector.  I consider this a bug - since it seems virtually impossible to not have a task kick off using the config previously passed to it, instead of using the current one.

Comment: I included a 2nd use case (similar issue) there.  Which is.. if you change the config on a paused sink connector (non-failed), if you update the config, and resume, it will update the config for the job, and start up a task..with the new config.. but it starts up that task before it updates the JDBC sink config..   Which means, the first worker task will run with the old config, subsequent run with the new.

Comment: unfortunately this is not working, because the task never restarts just says fail and does not try to pickup the new configuration

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem and managed to "fix" this by a bit of randomness.
I increased the number of Tasks in the connector and then reduced it again and it seemed to have picked up a new configuration.
Was really random.
I do know the restart did not work for me